# How to Add a Caption instead of Image URL on Facebook Sharer dialog

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

As I've found out Facebook now does not allow adding more parameters like Caption, Description on Sharer URL.

Anyway, little bit confused if it is possible to changed the Image Base URL (Domain name) appears on the image. (please see the image)

[image]

So, is there a way to customize the circled text appeared on the image ?

Comment: No. That is _supposed_ to show the actual domain of the shared content now, to help users spot fake news easier, etc. Suggest you share a proper HTML document (instead of just an image on its own) under your domain, and set the image as thumbnail.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks and noted!